# python re string starting with

Tags: python

In the following string how to say that the line is starting with a digit or ending with a number or many

```
line="He is a German called Mayer12345"
re.compile(r".*\d+\w$")

line="12He is a German called Mayer"
re.compile(r"^\d+\w .*")
```

Comment: If I understand right you just need: `r'(^\d.*)|(.*\d+$)'`

Comment: But if a digit exist there would be a word existing after that..how will u check for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the pipe, it's an or for regexes:

```
re.compile(r"(^\d+\w .*)|(.*\d+\w$)")
```